# DetailsView can't figure how to trigger update event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqldatasource, detailsview

I've been trying to make use of DetailsView for the past few days to show and edit data from a single record taken from a GridView, both read their datafrom an SqlDataSource.

I've been searching the internet and the MSDN for info about how to use a DetailsView to edit data and I managed to cobble something together, the problem is that apparently the actual updating method doesn't run.

So here's an extract of my code

GridView In the page:

```
                <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" AutoGenerateRows="False" DefaultMode="Edit">
                    <fields>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Codice Cliente">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCliCod" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.cli_cod") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCliCod" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.cli_cod")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Descrizione">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCliDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.cli_desc")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCliDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.cli_desc")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nome Utente">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCliUser" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.cli_user")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCliUser" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.cli_user")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCliPass" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.cli_pass")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCliPass" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.cli_pass")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amministratore">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCliAdmin" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.cli_admin")%>'></asp:Label>

                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCliAdminE" runat="server" Text='<%# CBool(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.cli_admin"))%>' />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <EditItemTemplate>

                                <asp:LinkButton Text="Aggiorna" ID="UpdateButton" runat="Server" CommandName="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton Text="Elimina" ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </fields>
                </asp:DetailsView>
```

Relevant parts of the Codebehind:

```
Private Sub SetupDataSource() 'this is the sqldatasource I'm using for the detailsview

    SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = Assist.connectionString
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = detailsSelect
    SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add(New Parameter("id"))

    SqlDataSource2.UpdateCommand = detailsUpdate
    SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters.Add(New Parameter("cli_cod"))
    SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters.Add(New Parameter("cli_desc"))
    SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters.Add(New Parameter("cli_user"))
    SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters.Add(New Parameter("cli_pass"))
    SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters.Add(New Parameter("cli_admin"))

End Sub

Private Sub SetupDetailsView(id As Int32)
    DetailsView1.AutoGenerateRows = False
    DetailsView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource2

    SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters("id").DefaultValue = id

End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    cn.Open()
    SetupDataSource()

   If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim id As String = Request.QueryString("id")
        If id <> "" Then

            SetupDetailsView(id)
            DetailsView1.DataBind()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

    Protected Sub DetailsView1_ItemUpdating(sender As Object, e As DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles DetailsView1.ItemUpdating
    Dim cliCod As String = (CType(DetailsView1.FindControl("txtCliCod"), TextBox)).Text.ToString()
    Dim cliDesc As String = (CType(DetailsView1.FindControl("txtCliDesc"), TextBox)).Text.ToString()
    Dim cliUser As String = (CType(DetailsView1.FindControl("txtCliUser"), TextBox)).Text.ToString()
    Dim cliPass As String = (CType(DetailsView1.FindControl("txtCliPass"), TextBox)).Text.ToString()
    Dim cliAdmin As Boolean = If((CType(DetailsView1.FindControl("chkCliAdminE"), CheckBox)).Checked = True, True, False)

    SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters("cli_cod").DefaultValue = cliCod
    SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters("cli_desc").DefaultValue = cliDesc
    SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters("cli_user").DefaultValue = cliUser
    SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters("cli_pass").DefaultValue = cliPass
    SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters("cli_Admin").DefaultValue = If(cliAdmin = True, "1", "0")


    DetailsView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

I'm either missing something or doing it wrong somewhere, which one is it and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert at using SqlDataSource, but you might try inserting a `SqlDataSource.Update` in your Item_Updating method:

```
SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters("cli_cod").DefaultValue = cliCod
SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters("cli_desc").DefaultValue = cliDesc
SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters("cli_user").DefaultValue = cliUser
SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters("cli_pass").DefaultValue = cliPass
SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters("cli_Admin").DefaultValue = If(cliAdmin = True, "1", "0")

SqlDataSource2.Update();

DetailsView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: I wish that were the problem, item_updating doesn't even get called when clicking on the update button

Comment: ok that was A problem, I must thank you for that, now I got to figure the other problem about the custom update button not calling the update method

Answer (score 0):

I use a DetailsView in an ongoing project.  They are finicky, but they work great when set up correctly.

Several potential issues I can see with your DetailsView are:

**Eval vs Bind**

As with all databound controls, Databinder.Eval is a read-only databind method.  To allow controls to automatically update, you must use Bind in the edit template.  Of course, you can manually update your database, but why reinvent the wheel?

> ```
> <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Codice Cliente">
> <ItemTemplate>
> <asp:Label ID="lblCliCod" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DataItem.cli_cod") %>'></asp:Label>
> </ItemTemplate>
> <EditItemTemplate>
> <asp:TextBox ID="txtCliCod" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DataItem.cli_cod")%>'></asp:TextBox>
> </EditItemTemplate>
> </asp:TemplateField>
> ```

**Built-in Update functionality vs manual update functionality**

You don't really need to use DetailsView1_ItemUpdating unless you are want to catch and modify values after submit and before committing to the datasource.  i.e. concatenating individual year/month/day textboxes into a single date.

However, since you are not currently generating an Update button (using property AutoGenerateEditButton="True"), you may need to handle the update manually as you are attempting.  Alternatively, for basic binding and update, I would comment out the updating functions, add the autogenerateeditbutton="True" property, and then try updating.

**Primary Key**

With some datasources, you must specify the DataKeyNames property (your primary key/s of your datasource) on the DetailsView to enable auto-binding.  I don't know for sure, but you may also need to set the DefaultMode property.

All properties and methods are explained well on the [MSDN DetailsView page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.aspx), but it's rather verbose.  The [MSDN Updating a DetailsView page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227560%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is more concise

Comment: this is really interesting, I've been doing all that eval stuff because that's what I found in an example somwhere, I'm still trying to figure fully how to manage all this stuff, still thanks for the tips

Comment: About the update button, I tried the integrated ones and they actually work, I still can't figure why custom buttons won't though, I recall an MSND article saying that any custom button with CommandName="Edit" would work